# Carrying user inputs from a textbox from one form to another

Tags: c#, arrays, forms, user-interface

I am making a program where the user can enter values in textboxes on one form and then the data will be carried over to the other form. I think the best way of doing this is to store the user data in several arrays and then carry those arrays over but at the moment I am having real trouble doing it. The textboxes are also created once the user has entered how many they require so the textboxes don't exist on the page initially

```
 string q = combobox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        int g = Convert.ToInt32(q);
        MessageBox.Show("I have added " +(g-1) +" Films to the list");
        TextBox[] FilmTitle1 = new TextBox[int.Parse(q)];
        TextBox[] FilmBudget1 = new TextBox[int.Parse(q)];
        TextBox[] FilmBoxOffice1 = new TextBox[int.Parse(q)];
        TextBox[] FilmDirector1 = new TextBox[int.Parse(q)];
        TextBox[] FilmRtScore1 = new TextBox[int.Parse(q)];
        TextBox[] FilmGenre1 = new TextBox[int.Parse(q)];
        int y = 500;
        for (int i = 0; i < g; i++)
        {
            FilmTitle1[i] = new TextBox();
            FilmTitle1[i].Text = "Film Title";
            FilmTitle1[i].Size = new Size(162, 20);
            FilmTitle1[i].Location = new Point(106, y);
            FilmTitle1[i].Tag = 0;
            this.Controls.Add(FilmTitle1[i]);
            y= y + 40;

private void Createbar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BarGraphCreation frm = new BarGraphCreation(FilmTitle.Text, FilmBudget.Text, FilmBoxOffice.Text, FilmDirector.Text, FilmGenre.Text, ft1, FilmBudget1.Text, FilmBoxOffice1.Text, FilmDirector1.Text, FilmGenre1.Text);
       frm.Show();
    }
```

But when I do it this way it says that there is no construct for textboxes despite the fact that it allows it everywhere else in the program.
Any type of help is extremely appreciated

Comment: Please enter the row where is `FilmTitle` defined and `BarGraphCreation()` constructor.

Comment: @Tatranskymedved its already there.. 4th code line down.

Comment: @BugFinder: I can see only invoke of the Constructor, but not it's definition. And unable to find `FilmTitle` (I can see only `FilmTitle1`).

Comment: TextBox is a normal windows control - you wouldnt get the constructor of textbox.

Comment: So `FilmTitle` is a `TextBox` or `TextBox[]` or `string` ?

Comment: you're looking at the createbar_click?

Comment: Cameron - which part is actually failing - the making of the text boxes or the clicking event?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Form
{
        // your code ...

        string q = combobox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        int g = Convert.ToInt32(q);
        MessageBox.Show("I have added " +(g-1) +" Films to the list");
        public TextBox[] FilmTitle1 = new TextBox[int.Parse(q)];
        public TextBox[] FilmBudget1 = new TextBox[int.Parse(q)];
        public TextBox[] FilmBoxOffice1 = new TextBox[int.Parse(q)];
        public TextBox[] FilmDirector1 = new TextBox[int.Parse(q)];
        public TextBox[] FilmRtScore1 = new TextBox[int.Parse(q)];
        public TextBox[] FilmGenre1 = new TextBox[int.Parse(q)];
        int y = 500;
        for (int i = 0; i < g; i++)
        {
            FilmTitle1[i] = new TextBox();
            FilmTitle1[i].Text = "Film Title";
            FilmTitle1[i].Size = new Size(162, 20);
            FilmTitle1[i].Location = new Point(106, y);
            FilmTitle1[i].Tag = 0;
            this.Controls.Add(FilmTitle1[i]);
            y= y + 40;

    private void Createbar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BarGraphCreation frm = new BarGraphCreation(this);
       frm.Show();
    }
}

public class BarGraphCreation
{
    // your code...

    Form form;
    public BarGraphCreation(Form form)
    {
        // ...
        this.form = form;
    }

    private void function()
    {
        // here you can work with your data like
        // form.FilmTitle1 and so on
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid passing whole objects like `TextBox` over to some other controls. General idea is You wan't to pass only data (information), always.

As the `Form` layout is created dynamically, the information about it's `Controls` should be held somewhere, where can be accessed again easily.

Example (including both array and list as an example):

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    private TextBox[] FilmTitles;
    private List<TextBox> FilmBudget = new List<Textbox>();

    //code removed for brevity

    private void Button1_Click( /***/ )
    {
        FilmBudget.Clear();

        int count = Convert.ToInt32(q);
        FilmTitles = new TextBox[count];

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            FilmTitles[i] = new TextBox()
            {
                Text = "Programmer in one day",
                Size = new Size(162, 20)
                // all other definitions
            };


            FilmBudget.Add(new TextBox()
            {
                Text = "1225",
                Size = new Size(162, 20)
                // all other definitions
            };

            this.Controls.Add(FilmTitles[i]);
            this.Controls.Add(FilmBudget[i]);

            //Now you are holding all the TB & text in global variables (arrays/lists)
        }
    }    

    private void Createbar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        BarGraphCreation frm = new BarGraphCreation(
               FilmTitles.Select( a => a.Text).ToArray(),
               FilmBudget.Select( a => a.Text).ToArray());
        frm.Show();
    }    

}
```

Where:

```
public class BarGraphCreation : Form
{
    public BarGraphCreation(string[] Titles, string[] Budgets)
    { }
}
```

Note that this part is using `LINQ` to select exact properties (values) into 2 arrays:

```
BarGraphCreation frm = new BarGraphCreation(
               FilmTitles.Select( a => a.Text).ToArray(),
               FilmBudget.Select( a => a.Text).ToArray());
```